# Date format on the output of cmdshell dir C:\ /TC

Tags: date, format

I would like to ask you guys if anyone of you had this trouble before.

In SQL I read the create time of the file like

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir C:\ /TC'
```

which gives me;

```
07/14/2009  04:20    <DIR>          Windows
```

As you noticed the date format of this is **mm/dd/yyyy** although it's set to **dd/mm/yyyy** format in region settings.

Same script on different PC returns

```
14/07/2009  04:20    <DIR>          Windows
```

- Is there any setting for this you guys aware ?
- And is there any method to change the format of create time of the
  command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date format of dd/mm/yy by using wmic command. This command allows you to get current date without getting affected by regional settings.

```
**@echo off

    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
        IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
            set /a FormattedDate=10000 * %%f + 100 * %%d + %%a
            set /a FormattedTime=%%b * 10000 + %%c * 100 + %%e
        )
    )

    for /f %%f in ("D:\Test*.zip") DO set filename=%%~nf
move "D:\Test*.zip" "D:\%FormattedDate%%FormattedTime%-%filename%.zip"**
```

You can save it as date.bat and run this batch file by executing the following in command prompt:

**C:>date.bat**